# eclipselink migration : could not find openjpa specific code

Tags: java, spring, migration, eclipselink, openjpa

I am migrating from openjpa (2.2.2) to eclipselink(2.5.2) in my legacy project.
During migration, I could see following code snippet which is specific to openjpa:

```
openjpaEntityManager kem = openjpaPersistence.cast(em);
kem.getFetchPlan().addField(Test.class, "stringvalue");
kem.getFetchPlan().addField(Test.class, "other string value");
if (!(em instanceof openjpaEntityManager)) {
kem.close();
}
```

Please help to find corresponding eclipselink related code to this code snippet.

Comment: Do you know what it does and how the EntityManager is used after this? What is "Test.class" used for in the rest of the class; are these two properties something you should just have been marking as eager?

Comment: @Chris , Test.class is an entity class and "stringvalue", "other string value" are two fields in it. in the docs I could see fetchplan is used for dynamically alter eager fetching configuration and other aspects of data loading.

"stringvalue" is of OneToMany and "other string value" is of ManyToOne with object type as Test

Comment: Right, but are those fields lazy to begin with? EclipseLink would require you to modify the mappings in the entity to change the fetch plan for the entity, which I wouldn't advise, and why JPA has entity graph support and fetch behavior in the queries you can use to fetch 'Test' instances.